# How can I give an element twice the space by css grids?

Tags: css

I want to divide the elements into four, but I want the first element to take twice the area. I tried to give item one display-template-columns 2fr but it doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem؟

```css
.container >div:nth-child(odd){   
background-color: rebeccapurple; 
}
.container >div:nth-child(even){
 background-color: red; 
}
item{
  
}
.container{   
display: grid;    
grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20%;  
grid-gap: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> NEW PRO </title>  
</head> 
<body>
<!--start-->
<div class="container"> 
<div class="item item1"> 
<h4>item1</h4>
</div>
<div class="item">  
<h4>item2</h4>
</div>
<div class="item"> 
<h4>item3</h4>
</div>
<div class="item"> 
<h4>item4</h4> 
</div>
</div>
<!--end-->
<script src="js/script.js"> 
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: `grid-column:span 2` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
.item1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 3;
}
```

If you use grid, you are counting the "grids", which is rows and columns. Think of it like an excel spreadsheet. Columns are vertical. Column lines is the lines before, after and between each column. In your code, you have five lines. 1 before, 3 between and 1 after.

With above code, you say that you want to start at Column Line 1, and end at Column 3. This means that your element will have twice the width in your case. If you add more columns, you need to change your grid column end.

Hope this makes things clear.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: @sshashank124 thanks for the comment. I now added explanation to the answer